# Chrome and Safari ajax issue with async:false

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I saw this everywhere on the web but i couldn't manage to fix my code to avoid this issue, simply I have an ajax function that I trigger when some buttons are clicked, sometimes I want an indicator (loading animation) to show, sometimes not, so i build my function:

```
function doAjax(action, todo, items, error_num, hide_indicator) {
  items.action = action;
  items.do = todo;
  var postedObj;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: ajaxURL,
    data: items,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      if (!hide_indicator) showIndicator();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        ajaxObj = JSON.parse(data);
        if (ajaxObj.ok) {
          postedObj = ajaxObj;
        } else {
          alert(ajaxObj.error);
          postedObj = false;
        }
      } else {
        alert('[' + error_num + '] Something went wrong.');
        postedObj = false;
      }
      if (!hide_indicator) hideIndicator();
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('[' + error_num + '] Something went wrong.');
      postedObj = false;
      if (!hide_indicator) hideIndicator();
    }

  });
    return postedObj;
}
```

And here is what I do on my buttons to call the function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ad-single', function() {
  var addataObj = doAjax('post_requests', 'get-ad-info', {"id": $(this).data('ad')}, '158', false); // false means DON'T hide the indicator
  if (addataObj) {
    loadContent(addataObj.ad);
  }  
});
```

OK, for now, everything works as expected on Firefox, when I click my button, the indicator shows up and wait until data is returned by ajax, then hide the indicator again.

This doesn't work on Chrome and Safari, the function works fine and return the data as expected but it seems that the `hideIndicator()` function is called immediately, I couldn't know how to fix this.

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome and Safari:

[image]

Comment: schronous calls lock up the block so the page does not have time to update. I am sure there are plenty of duplicates with this same question.

Comment: I know it does, but I can't remove it because it will return empty to my `loadContent` function!

Comment: That is why you make your code handles asynchronous request...

Comment: due to async call, maybe call the loading indicator before ajax call. try on top of $.ajax function, add this : if (!hide_indicator) showIndicator();

Comment: I tried, same thing, `hideIndicator()`is being called immediately even before the ajax call return the data from the server.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you are implementing the showIndicator() and hideIndicator() functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `async: false` is evil. The Internet is full of such posts, and many browsers including Chrome and Safari will give you numerous warnings on making synchronous AJAX requests.

Fortunately, jQuery's promises can be used to overcome your problem. It doesn't change how your function works, and leverages the power of promises too to make async requests.

You can modify your existing function as follows, so that it returns an AJAX promise, instead of the result.

```
function doAjax(action, todo, items, error_num, hide_indicator) {
  items.action = action;
  items.do = todo;

  return $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      url: ajaxURL,
      data: items,
      beforeSend: function() {
        if (!hide_indicator) showIndicator();
      }
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      if (!hide_indicator) {
        hideIndicator();
      }

      if (data) {
        ajaxObj = JSON.parse(data);

        if (ajaxObj.ok) {
          return ajaxObj;
        }

        alert(ajaxObj.error);
        return false;
      }

      alert('[' + error_num + '] Something went wrong.');
      return false;
    }, function() {
      if (!hide_indicator) {
        hideIndicator();
      }

      alert('[' + error_num + '] Something went wrong.');
      return false;
    });
}
```

Here, a `.then` function can be used to pre-process the response, and return the appropriate value to the subsequent promise handlers.

A subsequent promise handler can be implemented as follows, which calls the `doAjax` function, and reacts on the value returns by pre-processing.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ad-single', function() {
  doAjax('post_requests', 'get-ad-info', {"id": $(this).data('ad')}, '158', false)
    .then(function(addataObj) {
      if (addataObj) {
        loadContent(addataObj.ad);
      }
    });
});
```

Here, the `.then()` chains up with the previous `.then()`, and reacts on the value returned (which is received in `addataObj`). Note that it only reacts on the success of the AJAX call. If you want to handle the error response as well, you need to pass a second argument as a function to the `.then()` handler.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That's it thank you very much, can I ask for more please? can we make it in pure JavaScript? I'm using a framework with custom DOM and I don't want to include the whole jQuery file just to do the `.then` promise.