# Jquery function is not working in a synchronus order

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery functions for image upload and saved in to the path as well a check of image upload size and height and width. Both functions work fine, but not in a synchronous way. It jumps out on next function without getting the result of other one.

Whenever I upload an image, the "checkheightwidth" function will always return `false`.
What's gong wrong?

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#UploadImg").change(function(e) {
  if (checkFileDetails()) {
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $("#UploadImg").get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      data.append("MyImages", files[0]);
    }


    $.ajax({
      url: "/Image/UploadFile",
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: data,
      async: false,
      success: function(response) {
        //code after success
        $("#txtImg").val('/Upload/' + response);
        $("#imgPreview").attr('src', '/Upload/' + response);
      },
      error: function(er) {
        alert(er);
      }

    });
  } else {
    //alert('something went wrong');
    console.log('ss');
  }

});

function checkFileDetails() {


  var fi = document.getElementById('UploadImg');
  if (fi.files.length > 0) { // FIRST CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
    for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var fileName, fileExtension, fileSize, fileType, dateModified;

      // FILE NAME AND EXTENSION.
      fileName = fi.files.item(i).name;
      fileExtension = fileName.replace(/^.*\./, '');

      // CHECK IF ITS AN IMAGE FILE.
      // TO GET THE IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT, WE'LL USE fileReader().
      if (fileExtension == 'png' || fileExtension == 'jpg' || fileExtension == 'jpeg') {
        // readImageFile(fi.files.item(i));             // GET IMAGE INFO USING fileReader().
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        if (checkheightwidth(fi.files.item(i))) // GET IMAGE INFO USING other option().
        {

          return true
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {

        alert('Please upload image file..!!');
        $('#UploadImg').val('');
        return false;
        // IF THE FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE.

        //fileSize = fi.files.item(i).size;  // FILE SIZE.
        //fileType = fi.files.item(i).type;  // FILE TYPE.
        //dateModified = fi.files.item(i).lastModifiedDate;  // FILE LAST MODIFIED.

        //document.getElementById('fileInfo').innerHTML =
        //    document.getElementById('fileInfo').innerHTML + '<br /> ' +
        //    'Name: <b>' + fileName + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'File Extension: <b>' + fileExtension + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'Size: <b>' + Math.round((fileSize / 1024)) + '</b> KB <br />' +
        //    'Type: <b>' + fileType + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'Last Modified: <b>' + dateModified + '</b> <br />';
      }

    }

    // GET THE IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT USING fileReader() API.

  }
}


function checkheightwidth(imgfile) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = imgfile)) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
      var w = this.width;
      var h = this.height;

      if (w < 1024 && h < 790) {

        alert('Please upload high resolution image.');
        $('#UploadImg').val('');
        return false;

      } else {
        return true;
      }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    //return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="UploadImg" />
<br />
<p id="fileInfo"></p>
<img id="imgPreview" class="thumbnail" style="height:200px; width:200px" />
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn" type="button" data-clipboard-target="#txtImg" onclick="copytxt();">
            <i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Copy Image link" id="txtImg" class="form-control" aria-label="..." onchange="copytxt();" />

</div>
```

Comment: Use `async:false` is evil, mmmkay: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41756658/2181514

Comment: The problem with your code is `checkheightwidth` function doesn't return anything as you have commented `//return true;`. So it will return `undefined`. That's why you're getting `false` in `if condition`.

Comment: Hi Karan,
Thanks for answer , but if I uncomment return true so in any of the case it will true which is not workable also. I have to restrict image of lower resolution

Comment: You can check my answer. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Sure Karan, I will check this and thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you Karan It is working now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your code upload file code to some another function like `uploadFile` below. And then call this function from `img.onload` before `return true`.

Also as per comment from @freedomn-m you should not use `async:false`. Even from your code I can see that if you remove `async:false` then also it will not make any issue.

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#UploadImg").change(function(e) {
  if (checkFileDetails()) {} else {
    //alert('something went wrong');
    console.log('ss');
  }

});

function uploadFile() {
  var data = new FormData();
  var files = $("#UploadImg").get(0).files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append("MyImages", files[0]);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Image/UploadFile",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
      //code after success
      $("#txtImg").val('/Upload/' + response);
      $("#imgPreview").attr('src', '/Upload/' + response);
    },
    error: function(er) {
      alert(er);
    }

  });

}

function checkFileDetails() {

  var fi = document.getElementById('UploadImg');
  if (fi.files.length > 0) { // FIRST CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
    for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var fileName, fileExtension, fileSize, fileType, dateModified;

      // FILE NAME AND EXTENSION.
      fileName = fi.files.item(i).name;
      fileExtension = fileName.replace(/^.*\./, '');

      // CHECK IF ITS AN IMAGE FILE.
      // TO GET THE IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT, WE'LL USE fileReader().
      if (fileExtension == 'png' || fileExtension == 'jpg' || fileExtension == 'jpeg') {
        // readImageFile(fi.files.item(i));             // GET IMAGE INFO USING fileReader().
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        if (checkheightwidth(fi.files.item(i))) // GET IMAGE INFO USING other option().
        {

          return true
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {

        alert('Please upload image file..!!');
        $('#UploadImg').val('');
        return false;
        // IF THE FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE.

        //fileSize = fi.files.item(i).size;  // FILE SIZE.
        //fileType = fi.files.item(i).type;  // FILE TYPE.
        //dateModified = fi.files.item(i).lastModifiedDate;  // FILE LAST MODIFIED.

        //document.getElementById('fileInfo').innerHTML =
        //    document.getElementById('fileInfo').innerHTML + '<br /> ' +
        //    'Name: <b>' + fileName + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'File Extension: <b>' + fileExtension + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'Size: <b>' + Math.round((fileSize / 1024)) + '</b> KB <br />' +
        //    'Type: <b>' + fileType + '</b> <br />' +
        //    'Last Modified: <b>' + dateModified + '</b> <br />';
      }

    }

    // GET THE IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT USING fileReader() API.

  }
}


function checkheightwidth(imgfile) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = imgfile)) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
      var w = this.width;
      var h = this.height;

      if (w < 1024 && h < 790) {

        alert('Please upload high resolution image.');
        $('#UploadImg').val('');
        return false;

      } else {
        uploadFile();
        return true;
      }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    //return true;
  }
}
```